# MongoDB: $mergeObjects is overwriting object data in update pipeline

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

When using `$mergeObjects` in update pipeline, the original object is being
overwritten. Are there any alternatives to avoid this from happening or can `$mergeObjects` be used in any way to avoid this.

I have a document as follows:

```json
{
    "employment": {
      "selfEmployed": {
          "netProfit": 1000,
          "addbacks": [
              {
                "addbackId": "5a934e000102030405000001",
                "value": 1000,
              }
            ]
      }
    }
}
```

I have update data as follows:

```js
const update = {
    "selfEmployed": {
        "netProfit": 22,
    }
  };
```

The update query is:

```js
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "employment": {
        $mergeObjects: [
          "$employment",
          update
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

However `$mergeObjects` overwrites the object to give following result:

```json
  {
    "employment": {
      "selfEmployed": {
        "netProfit": 22
      }
    }
  }
```

Expected Result:

```json
{
    "employment": {
      "selfEmployed": {
          "netProfit": 22,
          "addbacks": [
              {
                "addbackId": "5a934e000102030405000001",
                "value": 1000,
              }
            ]
      }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/d_pGKC5bXsT)

**Edit 1:**

I can only rely on top level field to perform update.
Some answers below do work for `selfEmployed`.
But I have other fields on the collection as well.
e.g.

```json
{
    "employment": {
      "selfEmployed": {
          "netProfit": 1000,
          "addbacks": [
              {
                "addbackId": "5a934e000102030405000001",
                "value": 1000,
              }
            ]
      },
      "unemployed": {
          "reason": "some reason",
          //... other data
      }
      // .. other data
    }
}
```

And i don't want to repeat or write multiple queries for updating nested fields and using direct set is out of the question as well.
I'm looking for a way using the update pipeline as I have given above.

Answer (score 1):

According to [`$mergeObjects` Behaviour](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/#behavior),

> $mergeObjects overwrites the field values as it merges the documents. If documents to merge include the same field name, the field, in the resulting document, has the value from the last document merged for the field.

Hence, the original `employment.selfEmployed` will be replaced with the new value.

---

**Solution 1: Direct `$set` value for `employment.selfEmployed.netProfit`.**

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "employment.selfEmployed.netProfit": 22
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground for Solution 1](https://mongoplayground.net/p/P0B2WlQ6nLN)

---

**Solution 2: `$mergeObjects` for `employment.selfEmployed` only.**

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "employment.selfEmployed": {
        $mergeObjects: [
          "$employment.selfEmployed",
          {
            "netProfit": 22
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground for Solution 2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/V1D2fZvVKTx)

Comment: Yes you answer will work for one particular update. But there might not be one field to update only. I'll edit my answer properly!